# Why does `reinterpret_cast` not behave as the C++ standard says?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, type-conversion, standards

At the entry of `reinterpret_cast`, [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) says:

> An expression of integral, enumeration, pointer, or pointer-to-member
>   type can be converted to its own type.The resulting value is the same as the value of expression. (since C++11)

However, the following code cannot be compiled (clang 5.0 with `-std=c++1z`):

```
enum class A : int {};

int main()
{
    A a{ 0 };
    reinterpret_cast<int>(a); // error : reinterpret_cast from 'A' to 'int' is not allowed
}
```

Why does `reinterpret_cast` not behave as the C++ standard says?

Comment: That quote doesn't say anything about `reinterpret_cast<int>(a);`. It does say something about `reinterpret_cast<A>(a);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `a` is `A`, not `int`. The syntax `enum class A : int` makes `int` the *underlying type* of `A`, which is a special relationship, but not an "is-a" relationship.

(`static_cast` will perform this conversion.)

Answer (score 3):

`int` is the "underlying type", but the enumeration itself is a separate type.

From [dcl.enum]/5:

> **Each enumeration defines a type that is different from all other types.** Each enumeration also has an underlying type. The underlying type can be explicitly specified using an enum-base.